# Number of partitions of $n$ words with max size $k$ letters

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I'd like to find the number of possible partitions of a sentence of $n$ words, and each partition has a max size of $k$ letters. Words cannot be broken in the partition and the order must be retained in the partition. Also, all word length ($w_{i}$) $\leq$ $k$. Trying to get a closed form formula

For example, $k=8$ we can have

the rabit | runs | on the | street

I've tried to break down every word into it's own partition, so I get one way. Then there are n-1 ways to get n-1 partitions. Then for larger values I'm not sure how to guarantee each partition is less than k.

So a simplified example:

$a | b | c | d | e$

For $k = 2$, suppose I remove $2$ separaters:

$a b | c d | e$ ---> this is fine

a | b | c d e ----> this is not

Currently not sure what else to try.

Comment: What are you given? Each word length? Is this computational or you want a formula that might be ugly to compute?

Comment: Yes I'm given word length, say $w_i$. Need a closed formula in terms of $k$, $n$, and potentially $w_i$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3777962/811225 This can be used for the limiting cases

Comment: @humanlikely I am not sure if there would be a closed for for this. I am saying this because for each case you solve, there will be a closed form *approximation* and not a perfect one

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi At first glance, a few of the links you sent me treats the items identically; would they work in this case where word order needs to be preserved?

Comment: @humanlikely objects arent treated identically, the groups are...aah wait i have done a terrible mistake

Comment: Does word length include 0?

Comment: the question doesn't say but i don't think so; otherwise there'd be inf. no. of solutions i think